# How to combine consecutive observations together by group in Stata?

Tags: stata

I have a dataset of interviews between doctors and patients. There is a variable *QuestionNumber*; *Speaker*, which indicates if the doctor (MD) or patient (P) is speaking; *Speech*, which contains what the speaker said, and *Row*, which sorts the dataset chronologically.

```
Row    QuestionNumber    Speaker    Speech
 1     1                 MD         Permission to record?
 2     1                 P          Yes
 3     1                 MD         Great
 4     2                 MD         I'd like to ask you-
 5     2                 MD         What was that?
 6     2                 P          Excuse me (blows nose)
```

For every question number, I would like every other observation (row) to be the same speaker. However, as you can see in Question (2), MD speaks consecutively (rows 4 and 5). I would like to combine the speech in these observations--i.e., combine the text when the same speaker speaks consecutively, within the same Question number.

I would like to have the final dataset look like this:

```
Row    QuestionNumber    Speaker    SpeechNEW
 1     1                 MD         Permission to record?
 2     1                 P          Yes
 3     1                 MD         Great
 4     2                 MD         I'd like to ask you- What was that?
 5     2                 P          Excuse me (blows nose)
```

I can't seem to find an existing solution online. Any advice would be appreciated--thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
clear 
input Row    QuestionNumber    str2 Speaker    str42 Speech
 1     1                 MD         "Permission to record?"
 2     1                 P          "Yes"
 3     1                 MD         "Great"
 4     2                 MD         "I'd like to ask you-"
 5     2                 MD         "What was that?"
 6     2                 P          "Excuse me (blows nose)"
 end 

 bysort Question (Row) : generate Comment = sum(Speaker != Speaker[_n-1]) 
 bysort Question Comment (Row) : replace Speech = Speech[_n-1] + " " + Speech if _n > 1 
 by Question Comment : keep if _n == _N 

 list, sepby(Question) 

     +--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
     | Row   Questi~r   Speaker                                Speech   Comment |
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  1. |   1          1        MD                 Permission to record?         1 |
  2. |   2          1         P                                   Yes         2 |
  3. |   3          1        MD                                 Great         3 |
     |--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
  4. |   5          2        MD   I'd like to ask you- What was that?         1 |
  5. |   6          2         P                Excuse me (blows nose)         2 |
     +--------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This worked perfectly--thanks! The one part of the code I don't understand is `sum(Speaker != Speaker[_n-1])`. How does this work--what does `sum` do here?

Comment: This is a forum for programmers -- and it seems that you are not reading the  documentation of the program in question. That is not a good strategy. `help sum()`  tells you what `sum()` does, produce the cumulative or running sum. Every time the speaker changes, you add 1 to the sum so far. That includes the first  observation, as `Speaker[0]` is evaluated as missing and will therefore differ from `Speaker[1]`. More on essentially the same problem at https://www.stata-journal.com/article.html?article=dm0029 Section 4.

Comment: Otherwise put, true or false statements have value 1 when true and 0 when false. `sum()` adds the 1s and 0s and naturally the 1s bump up the sum and the 0s make no difference.

Comment: More on true and false at https://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/true-and-false/

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and additional resources. I'm not a programmer, but I am genuinely trying to learn and don't always know where to find the relevant information online. I did not know you could pair `sum` with a true and false statement--thanks again.

Comment: Thanks for the remarks. You should also consider posting on Statalist.